# How to get a string value in Xcode from ashx page?

Tags: xcode

I have a TextField in my Xcode appliation. Now I need to get a value from an ashx page. When I open that ashx page in browser, I can see that it is showing only a single value. I need to show that value in my TextField.

This is the ashx page:
somelink/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true

Please help me out...

Comment: I need it urgently. I do apologize as i'm very new to xCode programming. Please answer if anyone knows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection to get the string data. Here is the code:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rsbtelemax.com/VSServices/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true"]] returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(error.description);
NSLog(string);
```

Comment: Really? It returns 7.4003 USD for me. Can you post your code?

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rsbtelemax.com/VSServices/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true"]];
    NSString *strBal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    lblBalance.text = strBal;

Comment: While debugging I'm no receiving any value for data. It is showing as nil.

Comment: Does your url return a value? Did you try it in a web browser?

Comment: I have included http:// .. it is returning a value in web browser.. but in project i'm receiving nil value for data

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you try it and tell me what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

in HTML can do with the help of <  iframe> 
eg:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="50px" src="http://rsbtelemax.com/VSServices/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<p>When the target of a link matches the name of an iframe, the link will open in the iframe.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: User has asked help in ashx not in html!